# Do I need a transit visa for a layover of 5 hours at Suvarnavumi airport in Bangkok?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, paperwork, thailand

My itinerary is as follows:

```
Kolkata => Bangkok Suvarnabhumi (on Thai Airways)
Layover for 5.10 hours at BKK Suvarnabhumi 
Bangkok Suvarnabhumi => Viantiane (on Thai Smile)
```

Return:

```
Viantiane (Wattay International Airport) => Bangkok Suvarnabhumi (Thai Airways)
Layover 2.10 hours 
Bangkok Suvarnabhumi => Kolkata (Thai Airways)
```

So, I would like to know if I need to apply for a transit visa for Thailand.

Comment: the tag says `Indian-citizens` so I will assume this is for an Indian Passport.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume your passport requires a visa to visit Thailand.

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Passengers transiting through Bangkok (BKK) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 12 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
>
> This TWOV facility does **not** apply to passengers traveling
>      on Angkor Air (K6), Beijing Capital Airlines (JD), Business
>      Air (8B), Cebu Pacific (5J), Eaststar Jet (ZE), Golden
>      Myanmar Airlines (Y5), Indigo (6E), Jeju Air (7C), Jet Asia
>      Airways (JF), Jetstar (JQ), Jetstar Pacific (BL), Jin Air
>      (LJ), JuneYao Airlines (HO), Lao Central Airlines (LF),
>      Mandara Airlines (RI), Norwegian Air (DY), Okay Airways
>      BK), Orient Thai Airlines (OX), Regent Air (RX), Shandong
>      Airlines (SC), Shanghai Airlines (FM), Shenzhen Airlines
>      (ZH), Siberia Airlines (S7), Sichuan Airlines (3U), South
>      East Asian Airlines (DG), Spice Jet (SG), **Thai Smile
>      Airlines (WE)**, Tianjin Airlines (GS), Tiger Air (TR), Trans
>      Aero (UN), Turkmenistan Airlines (T5), T'way Airlines (TW),
>      Ural Airlines (U6) and VietJet Air (VJ).

**However**, for entering Thailand:

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of India with a normal
>   passport traveling as tourists can obtain a visa on arrival at
>   Bangkok (BKK and DMK) [...] for
>   a maximum stay of 15 days. They must have a  confirmed return/onward ticket with a departure within 15  days from arrival date, 1 recent passport photo and at least  THB 10,000.- per person (or THB 20,000.- per family). Their  passport must contain at least 1 unused visa page.

This means you don't need a visa in advance; should you need to clear immigration at any point (which TIMATIC suggests you have to do), get a visa at the airport before doing so.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, however, I'm not sure if Thai Smile Airways is the same one as the one I have booked as the flight number is TG 2570 and not WE. And the logo displayed in the ticket is the same as Thai Airways.

Comment: @PrithaB It's a code share flight, with the actual flight number being WE570. However, if it's in a single booking **AND** TG 2570 is what your ticket says (double check this on Thai's Website, by entering your booking code there) you don't need a visa.

Comment: Thanks, the ticket says Thai Airways TG 2570 operated by Thai Smile, and yes, it is a single booking. Could you share the Thai website you're speaking of, I checked at cleartrip with my booking ID.@coke

Comment: @PrithaB https://www.thaiairways.com/en_IN/Manage_My_Booking/My_Booking.page?

Comment: @PrithaB Double-checked, you don't need a visa since it's in a single booking, and even if you did, you can get it on Arrival.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is at the same airport (BKK), I don't see the need to pass through immigration unless the terminal you need to get through is such that you are forced to do so in order to get there.  My understanding is that [you can switch terminals in transient *without having to pass through immigration*](http://www.thaiembassy.org/telaviv/en/services/685/17388-Entry-to-Thailand.html).

Unless you must actually go through Thai arrival immigration (and subsequently Thai departure immigration), **you do not need a visa**.  So the central question is, do you need to pass through immigration to catch your connecting flight?  It doesn't appear so based on the information you provided so far.

In case you determine you must pass through immigration before you can get to the next plane, you have 2 options:

1) [only before departing] Obtain a Single Entry Tourist Visa (SETV) from the Thai Embassy in India or country in which you are a local resident.

2) Obtain a Visa on Arrival (VoA) at the airport. But you can obtain a Visa On Arrival which is 2,000 Baht (increased from 1,000 Baht effective Sept 2017).  You may also need passport size photos which can be done on site for additional fee.  I recommend you bring your own photos.

Keep in mind that to obtain VoA may take <s>an hour</s> [2-3 hours (read post #16)](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293915-i3686-k10822963-o10-Thailand_On_Arrival_Visa_Fees_for_Indians-Thailand.html).  You claim that there is a 5 hour layover.  Assuming the plane is on time, should be no worries.